# AzureRunAsConnection ApplicationId and CertificateThumbprint

Tags: azure, azure-devops

hi all where can i find  CertificateThumbprint  and  ApplicationId ??
I have tenant Id but i dont know the rest .

Thanks.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
```

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Could you get these two parameters value with the below steps? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some puzzle about them, please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Answer (score 3):

> ApplicationId

To get this ApplicationId, you need to register one Application in AAD:

[image]

After the application registered successfully in AAD, you will be redirected into the page which display the details about this application. Then you can see its `ApplicationId`:

[image]

> CertificateThumbprint

Just go left bar, open **Certificates & secrets** tab. Then Upload a Certificates for this application. After the upload succeed, its CertificateThumbprint will appear under the column of **THUMBPRINT**.

[image]